# In Swift, how should I save data from a custom view so that it is not deleted when a cell is dequeued?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a custom view that exists in a cell in a tableview. The view is called bulletRow and it is a series of bullets that can be filled in or emptied when a user taps on them. Each cell in my tableview contains some bulletRows and I need to save them when the user taps on them. I have considered using Core Data, but I don't need them to persist when the app is shut down, I only need it to exist when the user scrolls past the dequeueing point.

Here is my situation right now: The default state for bulletRows is to have 5 dots, all of them empty. When a user taps on them they become filled. If the user scrolls down however, they get reset back to being empty. How can I save the state of the bulletRows?

The bulletRows have a property called numberOfFilledCircles which can be set at anytime to change the amount of filled in circles. This is all done in Swift as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should use something, such as an array, to hold the state of your table. The cells in your table should reflect that state, and update that state when selected.

You might start with an array of integers in your table view controller, like this:

```
var numberOfFilledCircles = [Int]()
```

Use the number of items in your array to determine how many rows to display in your table, by returning `numberOfFilledCircles.count` from your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

You can populate the array in `viewDidLoad`. If you're hardcoding the rows, you can repeat this statement for as many rows you want:

```
numberOfFilledCircles.append(0)
```

Each `Int` in the array holds the value representing how many circles are filled (initialize to 0).

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, use the appropriate value from your array when constructing your cell. For example, if your cell had a `UILabel` called `numberOfFilledCircles`, you would do this:

```
cell.numberOfFilledCircles.text = String(numberOfFilledCircles[indexPath.row])
```

Finally, in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, update the array with the number of circles you want filled in:

```
numberOfFilledCircles[indexPath.row] = //whatever you want
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! Is it common to create your model (array) within the view controller?

Comment: Glad to help. If your data never changes, then yes, you can create the model in your view controller. However, it's more common that the data varies. You would usually have some other structure that would serve as your model, such as a web service response or Core Data database fetch result.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the UI is not the model.

When the ui elements are pressed, you should send an action to the underlying model to update its state, and when cells are dequeued you should restore the checkbox state from the appropriate model element.

Comment: Do you know of a guide to handling data in a model? I'm not really sure how to build a data model outside of the UI

Comment: You should look at some tutorials on the Model View Controller (MVC) design pattern. To get you started... http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns ... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html