# How to manage custom cell label value in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction, uitableview

I’m building an iOS app using storyboards.I have used UITableViewController which has 6 custom cells each of which contains three IBOutlet buttons and one IBOutlet label.

When the user clicks on any button in one particular custom cell, then the value of only that particular cell label should change.

But what happens is, values of all labels in each custom cell get changed.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *Cellidentifier1 = @"List";
    Cell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    // Configure the cell...

    long row = [indexPath row];

    cell1.First.tag=row;//button iboutlet in cell
    cell1.Second.tag=row;//button iboutlet in cell
    cell1.Third.tag=row;//button iboutlet in cell

    cell1.Level.tag=row;

    cell1.Level.text=Skill;//label iboutlet in cell

    return cell1;
 }


-(IBAction)FirstAction:(id)sender{

     Skill=@"first";
     [self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(IBAction)SecondAction:(id)sender{

     Skill=@"Second";
     [self.tableView reloadData];

}


-(IBAction)ThirdAction:(id)sender{

     Skill=@"Third";
     [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: You are setting Skill when first action is clicked, then reloading your table and setting every cell to have the value in Skill. You need an array of Skills.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Thanks for reply this is not what i want to do,so there are buttons in cell by clicking those cell value of label changed but right now its changing in all cells but i want when user click on button in a particular cell then the value label of that particular cell changed.

Comment: I'm guessing at some point you will want to do something with the Skill data besides display it. If you just focus on the display problem, you are going to be disappointed when you actually try to use the information you've collected from your user. To avoid this disappointment requires you to think about how to use table views properly. My answer here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036277/in-swift-how-should-i-save-data-from-a-custom-view-so-that-it-is-not-deleted-wh/28036626#28036626

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. You should have a model that reflects what's in your table view. Specifically, right now you have a single `Skill` value, but you have six rows. You want to maintain a model that is an array of values, something like:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *values;
   ```

   And

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       self.values = [@[@"first", @"first", @"first", @"first", @"first", @"first"] mutableCopy];
   }
   ```

   And

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       static NSString *Cellidentifier1 = @"List";
       Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];

       NSString *value = self.values[indexPath.row];

       cell.level.text = value;

       return cell;
   }
   ```

   Note, no tag numbers needed.
2. When you tap on a button you must (a) identify what row in the table that corresponds to; (b) update that row in your model; and (c) reload that single row in the table (which will look up the value in the model):

   ```
   - (void)updateCell:(UIView *)cell withValue:(NSString *)value {
       NSParameterAssert(cell);

       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell];
       if (cell) {
           self.values[indexPath.row] = value;
           [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       }
   }

   - (IBAction)didTapFirstButton:(id)sender {
       [self updateCell:[[sender superview] superview] withValue:@"first"];
   }

   - (IBAction)didTapSecondButton:(id)sender{
       [self updateCell:[[sender superview] superview] withValue:@"second"];
   }

   - (IBAction)didTapThirdButton:(id)sender{
       [self updateCell:[[sender superview] superview] withValue:@"third"];
   }
   ```

   Note, the `sender` is the button. So I get the table view cell by grabbing the `superview` (which is the cell's content view) and then grab its `superview` (the cell itself). If your view hierarchy is different, then change that as appropriate, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: hi @Rob could you please help me i want to increase the size button which is clicked in particular cell and tried to update the CGRect of button when it is clicked but that is not working.

Comment: The answer is a little complicated (it depends upon what iOS version you have, whether you're using auto-layout or not, whether the button is configured to translate its frame into constraints, etc.). It's better for you to layout all of the details in a new Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to do is that use delegate method `selectRowAtIndexPath` when the row is selected then the indexPath selected row buttons can be used...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

}
```

when the row is selected then that desired rows button functions will be performed

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *Cellidentifier1 = @"List";
    Cell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    // Configure the cell...

    long row = [indexPath row];

    cell1.First.tag=row;//button iboutlet in cell
    cell1.Second.tag=row;//button iboutlet in cell
    cell1.Third.tag=row;//button iboutlet in cell

    cell1.Level.tag=row;

    cell1.Level.text=Skill;//label iboutlet in cell
[cell1.First addTarget:self action:@selector(FirstAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell1.Second addTarget:self action:@selector(SecondAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell1.Third addTarget:self action:@selector(ThirdAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell1;
 }
```

Comment: thanks @Dipel i applied your code but it is giving same result.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do it. But, from looking at your code I would make sure you get the right indexPath from the cell you selected. Assuming you have the target action already set up, you could rewrite your IBAction method like so:

```
-(IBAction)firstAction:(UIButton *)sender{
    int row = sender.tag;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:row inSection:0];
    Cell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Skill = @"first";
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

this is going to get the right cell and index path. Update that cell's label only and then reload it.

Comment: thanks for reply @Alex  int row = sender.tag; here it is giving error   Property 'tag' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Comment: you have to change the    id    in the method signature to UIButton * ,   i.e.   -(IBAction)firstAction:(UIButton *)sender,  since id's don't have tags

Comment: Do not just update the label on the cell. Update the model backing the tableview (which means changing the model so it keeps track of the state of each of the rows of the table), and then reload the cell. This is critical. If you only update the cell label, if the cell scrolls out of view and is reused for another row of the table, you lose what the user did.

Answer (score 0):

In your IBOutlet methods add this to find the indexPath for the row

```
CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
```

instead of reloading the entire tableview you only want to reload the text for that cell at that specified `indexPath`

To reload only one cell, do **this instead of** `[self.tableView reloadData];`

`[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[hitIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`